# Team admins have a diamond rather than a hexagon on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-for-teams, mobile-web

When viewing a team admin's profile via mobile (or setting the device type on desktop with debugging tools), their name has a diamond appended, rather than a hexagon.

Mobile view:

[image]

Desktop view:

[image]

Comment: They are evolving so fast! Climbing the ladder of regular polygon.

Comment: From 4 sides to few millions aside: The evolution from a polygon to a Carlos Gon.

Comment: You have to look at from different angle: Having fewer angles makes you more sharp!

Comment: Proposal to have 10-dimensional polytope icons for moderators

Comment: Proposal to have circles for users.

Comment: Jon skeet should have a [Tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract) preferably represented in all [4 dimensions](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/8-cell.gif).

Comment: @Liam a Megagon would be more in line, due to his rep.

Comment: it's a diamond on desktop for me. Using Firefox, no debugging stuff active

Comment: What view is this? Clicking *mobile* in footer gives a different header bar and the profile pages are not yet responsive for me.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard Clicking the mobile link does reproduce the effect. I noticed it first on my actual mobile going to the main site (not an app). Also reproducing by setting the device type with debug tools and refreshing the page

Comment: This is definitely a bug; that polygon should have 8 sides, not 6 (4 sides for being a diamond mod, and another 4 for team lead).

Comment: Does it also happen for admins who aren't mods on main? I would think so, but we can never be sure :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Indeed it does, I checked a few admin accounts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've fixed this bug and it is live now.

After adding the new mod flair for Teams admins, we moved all instances of mod flair generation to a standardized function. I took a look around the codebase and this was the only instance of mod flair that I could find that wasn't using this function. It would seem that you found the only remaining item that was not migrated!

Thank you for your report.